# Module notation

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation, modules

Suppose I have a ring $R$ whose underlying group is $G$.

Now suppose I read the definition:

> Let $M$ be an $n$-dimensional **left module** over $R$.

Is this a conventional way of defining $M$ as being $G^n$ over $R$ where $G^n$ is a repeated direct product of $G$ with itself?

Also: a module's abelian group need not be the same group underlying its *ring*, correct?

Comment: It's not 100% clear what it means. It could be what you say (and probably is), with if eg $R$ is a PID, it could mean that $M$ is a finitely generated module with torsion free part equal to $R^n$... It's primarily the absence of the adjective "free" that muddies things.

Comment: This somewhat depends on what notion of *dimension* you are working with. Can you please tell us what that is?